# MvC multiple submits diffrent columns same row

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, view, model, controller, submit

So this is the code, i have 2 submit buttons when i press "Start" I want it to send the Datetime.now to the start row, and when i press "Stop" i want it to send the Stop datetime.now to the column, this should be happening in the same row. And when i press Start again it should generate a new ID 2, etc. print the start date on the second row.

Exampel ID 1 : Start 2013-11-15 05:12 Slut : 2013-11-15 05:15

Greetings Patrik

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Start, new { style = "display: none;", @Value = @DateTime.Now })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Start)
        </div>
         <p>
            <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)" value="Start" formaction="/tider/create" />
        </p>

    }
    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Slut)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Slut, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Slut)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)"  value="Stop" />
        </p>
    }
</fieldset>

            <div class="editor-label">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Slut)
            </div>
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Slut, new { @Value = @DateTime.Now })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Slut)
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    }
```

controller 
    {
        public class TiderController : Controller
        {
            private TiderDBContext db = new TiderDBContext();

```
        //
        // GET: /Tider/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Tider.ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Tider/Details/5

        public ActionResult Details(int id = 0)
        {
            ArbetsTider arbetstider = db.Tider.Find(id);
            if (arbetstider == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Tider/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        //
        // POST: /Tider/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(ArbetsTider arbetstider)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Tider.Add(arbetstider);
                db.SaveChanges();

            }

            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Tider/Edit/5

        public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
        {
            ArbetsTider arbetstider = db.Tider.Find(id);
            if (arbetstider == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Tider/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit(ArbetsTider arbetstider)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(arbetstider).State = EntityState.Modified;

               return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Tider/Delete/5

        public ActionResult Delete(int id = 0)
        {
            ArbetsTider arbetstider = db.Tider.Find(id);
            if (arbetstider == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(arbetstider);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Tider/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            ArbetsTider arbetstider = db.Tider.Find(id);
            db.Tider.Remove(arbetstider);
            db.SaveChanges();
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Start(ArbetsTider model)
        {
            using (var context = new TiderDBContext())
            {
                context.Tider.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.ID).Start = model.Start;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Stop(ArbetsTider model)
        {
            using (var context = new TiderDBContext())
            {
                context.Tider.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == model.ID).Slut = model.Slut;
                context.SaveChanges();
            }
            return View("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

model

```
public class ArbetsTider
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public DateTime Slut { get; set; }

}

public class TiderDBContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<ArbetsTider> Tider { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Ajax method to submit the one form partially without refreshing the whole page.

Try something like this:

**First change  like this(remove type='submit'):**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Tider", FormMethod.Post, new { @id= "formStart" } ))
    {
// html code
    <input id="submittStartDate" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)" value="Start" class="submitButton" />
});
```

And

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Stop", "Tider", FormMethod.Post, new { @id= "formStop" } ))
{
//html 
    <input id="stop" name="@Html.NameFor(x => x.Command)"  value="Stop" class="submitButton" />
//html 
});
```

**Then add a function in javascript file:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input.submitButton").click(function() {
      SubmitForm(this);
   });
});

function SubmitForm(input) {
   var url = "";
   var formData = "";

   if(input[0].id == "formStart")
   {
      url = "../Tider/Create";
      data = $('form#formStart').serialize();
   }
   else if(input[0].id == "formStop") {
      url = "../Tider/Stop";
      data = $('form#formStop').serialize();
   }

   $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: data,
       success: function (result) {
          // Do your stuff here
       },
       error: function () {
         alert("Error in saving");
       }
    });
}
```

You need to change the return types of the C# methods Create and Stop to required type(I think you need int here) and retun that. And you will get the data "success" function of the Ajax call.